# Two radio buttons, One div -- conditionally toggling one div via two radio button selections

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, toggle, show-hide

I'm trying to toggle one div via two radio buttons. If the value to either question (emStudent & anotherDegree) or both questions is "Yes" then the div (#student-discount-wrap) appears. I have it working for if emStudent value is "Yes," but I'm not really sure how to set up the "or" conditional for anotherDegree. I've tried a couple of || statements but haven't been able to get anything to work. Help meeeeee! :(

Here's my html:

```
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-12"  for="emStudent"><strong>Are you a student:</strong></label><br/>
    <div class="radio col-sm-12">
        <label><input type="radio" class="cbct-radio" name="emStudent" value="Yes" id="emYes">Yes</label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio col-sm-12">
        <label><input type="radio" class="cbct-radio" name="emStudent" value="No" id="emNo">No</label><br/>
        <label for="emStudent" class="error"></label>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-12"  for="anotherDegree"><strong>Are you a student at another degree or certificate-granting program:</strong></label><br/>
        <div class="radio col-sm-12">
            <label><input type="radio" class="cbct-radio" name="anotherDegree" value="Yes" id="anotherYes">Yes</label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio col-sm-12">
            <label><input type="radio" class="cbct-radio" name="anotherDegree" value="No" id="anotherNo">No</label><br/>
            <label for="anotherDegree" class="error"></label>
        </div>
    </div><div class="form-group row" id="student-discount-wrap">
        <label class="col-sm-12"  for="studentDiscount"><strong>For Student Discount:</strong> Please list your institution and expected date of graduation (or graduate program). If a student, list your school e_mail address above. Other students may be asked to provide additional documentation.</label><br/>

        <textarea name="studentDiscount" id="studentDiscount" class="form-control col-sm-12 textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
```

And here's my JS for the one radio button toggling the div:

```
$("input:radio[name='emStudent']").click(function(){ 
        if(this.value == "Yes"){
            $("#student-discount-wrap").show();
        }else{
        // hide the dependent fields and blank them
            $("#student-discount-wrap").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: In simpler terms, if both radios are `No`, hide the DIV ?

Comment: @adeneo - You know, after sitting here for hours trying to think up how to set up the conditionals (among other things I'm doing for this form), I didn't even think about it that way.

Comment: That happens to me as well, conditionals often seem more complicated than they are when you have some preconception of how you think they should work. A new set of eyes often helps.

Comment: @adeneo Definitely! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by selecting both radio groups, then add a `change` event handler, and see if any of the groups has a `checked` radio with the value `Yes`

```
var radios = $("input[type=radio][name='emStudent'], input[type=radio][name='anotherDegree']");

radios.on('change', function() {
    var hasYes = radios.filter(function() {
        return this.checked && this.value === 'Yes';
    }).length > 0;

    $("#student-discount-wrap").toggle(hasYes);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oup2kx39/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use another simple way:

```
$(".cbct-radio").click(function(){ 
    if($('.cbct-radio[value="No"]:checked').length == 0) { // if no radio with class ".cbct-radio" and value "No" is checked
        $('#student-discount-wrap').show();
    } else {
        $('#student-discount-wrap').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I wish I could give you an up, but I don't have enough rep points yet. :(